# "can't convert BigDecimal into String" on Ruby 1.9.2p290, but not on 1.9.3p0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a scenario with code like the following:

```
extracted_data = data.map{|row| ((row.some_long_number.to_f) if BigDecimal(row.some_long_number) != BigDecimal("-1500.0")) }.reverse
```

When I run this on Rails 3.1.x with ruby 1.9.3 it works out fine, however when I shift this over to Heroku Cedar with the same Rails version but ruby 1.9.2, I end up with the following exception:

```
can't convert BigDecimal into String

app/controllers/some_controller.rb:12:in `BigDecimal'
app/controllers/some_controller.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in index'
app/controllers/some_controller.rb:12:in `map'
app/controllers/some_controller.rb:12:in `block in index'
app/controllers/some_controller.rb:3:in `new'
app/controllers/some_controller.rb:3:in `index'
```

What could be going on here from ruby 1.9.2 to 1.9.3 that sets this off?

Comment: Is `some_long_number` a decimal or numeric column in the database?

Comment: So in this case the long number is a number such as `0.000000153000` in the database and it's schema entry is: `t.decimal "some_long_number", :precision => 18, :scale => 12`

Comment: Then AR will convert it to a BigDecimal when it pulls it out of the database and Michael has it right. You don't need `BigDecimal(row.some_long_number)` as `row.some_long_number` is already a BigDecimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Ruby changelog:

- bigdecimal/bigdecimal.c (BigDecimal_new): support generating a new
    BigDecimal from another BigDecimal using BigDecimal global function
    or constructor.  [ruby-dev:44245]

I suspect that `BigDecimal(row.some_long_number)` is making a `BigDecimal` of something that is already a `BigDecimal`.  The constructor takes a String, so it is trying to coerce the BigDecimal to a string.  The change in 1.9.3 allows for this, but 1.9.2 doesn't.

So you can do something like:

`row.some_long_number.respond_to?(:to_s) ? BigDecimal(row.some_long_number) : row.some_long_number`

Comment: If `some_long_number` is decimal, numeric, or money inside the database and `data` is coming out of ActiveRecord then `some_long_number` will be a BigDecimal already and you're probably right. Good guess even if you turn out to be wrong.

Comment: Interesting.  When printing out the row.some_long_number.class I see that it is returning BigDecimal.  So in this case the row.some_long_number.class is BigDecimal.  Would the issue be coming into play when "-1500.00" is coerced to BigDecimal then?  If so or otherwise, what do you suggest for addressing this situation as it's not yet evident where I should go with this instance.

Comment: Yeah the string is OK, but the `BigDecimal(another_big_decimal)` is not going to work in 1.9.2 because the constructor can only take a string.  1.9.3 changed this behavior.  If you know it is always a BigDecimal I would just not try and make it one again.  You can do something that detects if it is a string, and if so makes it a big decimal, else leave alone.